# How to split and combine files

Tags: windows

How do I split and combine files in Windows?

I need to split large files into several small sized files and then combine them after I transfer them to another box.

I'm fine with doing this on the command line.

Comment: You can alternatively use [GSplit](https://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit). I found the utility incredibly helpful when I have to move large files to a hard disk that has a FAT32 file system. This program also creates an executable which can unite all the files after splitting them in the destination directory, which is very helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tend to compress the required file to a ZIP file, setting a maximum file size so that it gets split.

This means that you will always have the program to get the initial file back available.

Comment: Addendum: 7-Zip can zip and split. Look for "Split to volumes, bytes", lower left corner when creating an archive in the GUI.

Comment: it can split even without archiving, just like the rest.

Comment: I tried this one. Very nice! The size of the package is about 1MG, less than GSplit (1.5MG). I need this tool to transfer files to a remote through a very slow connection. Therefore, the size of app is very important.

Comment: @David.Chu.ca Have a look at portable-apps various compressors, like portable-apps 7zip

Comment: You can alternatively use [GSplit](https://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit). I found the utility incredibly helpful when I have to move large files to a hard disk that has a FAT32 file system. This program also creates an executable which can unite all the files after splitting them in the destination directory, which is very helpful.

Answer (score 40):

If you just want to combine files (which have already been split somewhere else) you can do this in a Windows command prompt natively:

```
copy /b example.ext.001+example.ext.002+example.ext.003+example.ext.004 example.ext
```

Comment: Note that Powershell also has a cmdlet `Copy-Item` with the alias `copy`. This cmdlet works differently.

Answer (score 14):

Use **[HJSplit](http://www.freebyte.com/hjsplit/)**. It is simply the best.

*HJSplit is freeware and portable (300 KB), and it doesn't have to be installed.*

There is an older free [command-line version](http://www.lawrencegoetz.com/programs/gfs101.zip) of **[Goetz's File Splitter](http://www.lawrencegoetz.com/programs/gfsplit.htm)**. You may like this version if you plan on running batch scripts to split lots of files.

**[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)** is another free open source program that allows you split (with or without compression) and combine files, either via GUI (right click on the file → *Split File...* → choose size) or command line.

If you have **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)**, it does that as well (Files → *Split File*...)

Answer (score 13):

For splitting files to exact sizes, you could always use the Linux / Unix command-line tool `split`. The Windows version is here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Using the tool, you can split files to any size you would like, and you would use "cat" to recombine them.

For example:

```
split -b=10090000 bigfile.iso bigfile_part.
```

To split your files to exactly 10090000 bytes.
Your output would look something like this:

```
bigfile_part.aa
bigfile_part.ab, etc.
```

To recombine, just do:

```
cat bigfile_part* > bigfile.iso
```

Comment: How do I split a stream.  Trying to do this:  some_long_running_data_process | split -l 10000 --name the_parts

Comment: Please correct: the option is `--b`, not `-b`.

Comment: Are you sure that `cat` guarantees that the output is ordered alphabetically? Because if it doesn't, the command will not fail with an error but just produce a different (and wrong) output.

Comment: @mgr326639 Yes, globbing expansion is alphabetical. https://serverfault.com/a/122743

Comment: `split` also has the ability to define MB, GB...: `split --bytes 11MB bigfile.iso bigfile.iso.`.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this:

```
type file1 file2 file3 > out
```

Comment: This only works for text files, **and** you are not adrressing how the OP can split the large files.

Comment: Did you test it before posting this claim? It actually works well for binary data as well.

Comment: Elmo - your solution worked GREAT! Thanks a ton! I had a multi-part binary that I easily pieced back together using this.

Comment: @nyxgeek well not that great. The correct way to combine binary files on Windows is `copy /b` like [user190976's answer](http://superuser.com/a/718901/241386) above

Comment: @ElmoTodurov did you read what MS said: ["If you display a binary file or a file created by a program, you may see strange characters on the screen, including formfeed characters and escape-sequence symbols. These characters represent control codes used in the binary file. In general, avoid using the type command to display binary files."](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491026.aspx). You'll see big difference if there is any `\n` or `\r` character in the stream

Comment: Sure, but I'm not displaying them. See the `> out` part? It redirects the output into the resulting file. Nothing is typed into the terminal.

Comment: If a binary file contains 0x1A, which MSDOS used as 'end-of-file' marker, Windows CMD `type` truncates it, at least though 10 (I don't have 11); other binary data is okay when redirected. But `type multiple file names` inserts headers (the filename surrounded by blank lines) which usually screws up your data; I'm mystified how this worked for nyxgeek. (In Powershell `type` is actually an alias for `get-content`, which can handle binary and doesn't accept multiple filenames at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**WinRAR**](http://www.rarlab.com/) as a file splitter/joiner as well. To split a file into smaller files, select "**Store**" as the compression method and enter the desired value (bytes) into "**Split to volumes**" box. This way you can have split files named as *filename.part1.rar*, *filename.part2.rar*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [GSplit](http://www.gdgsoft.com/download/gsplit.aspx). It's a powerful and free file splitter that lets you split your large files into a set of smaller files called *pieces*.

Answer (score 0):

In Cygwin (basic install), Bash shell:

```
dd if=archive.tar bs=512M | xz -e9fc | split -b4000m - /destination/path/archive_split.
```

Omit the xz pipe block if your archive is already
compressed.

To splice your archive together:

```
cat archive_split.* > archive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
https://sakaiws.com/tools/en/FileDivider

Files aren't uploaded to the server so it's safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, you can install the file splitter module:

```
install-module filesplitter
```

Then you use the following command to split a file:

```
split-file "<absolute path to large file>" -PartSizeBytes 500MB
```

to split it into chunks of 500MB size.

To combine the junks to the original file, simply use the following CMD command:
copy /b chunkfile1 + chunkfile2 + ... chunkfileX 
(see answer by @user190976)

Comment: Has a file size limit. I am guessing 2GB like `Compress-Archive`.

Answer (score -1):

None of the other answers work for me.  This one did,

```
Get-Content inputFile1.txt, inputFile2.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

OR

```
Get-Content inputFile*.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

More info in:

- This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750029/2601293)
- This [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1760692/1210833)

Comment: While you did the right thing by attributing the Stack Overflow answer, it appears to me you likely initially saw it on [@harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1760692/1210833), since you also answered the same question yesterday.  It would be nice to attribute both of them, IMHO, since I don't think you would have found the SO answer without @harrymc's.  I'm going to make the edit to this answer to include both, but please do rollback my edit if I'm wrong about this.  Thanks!