# Making Mac OS X split .rar files available to non-mac users

Tags: macos, winrar

I've split a 8 GB `my_doc.rar` file into 4 separate files using the following command from my Mac OS X 10.9 terminal

```
split -b 2000m my_doc.rar my_doc.rar
```

After splitting the file I've generated: `my_doc.raraa`, `my_doc.rarab`, `my_doc.rarac`, and `my_doc.rarad`. Can I make the 4 files `.rar` just by removing the extensions? No, because I tried to extract those using UnRarX by renaming as `my_doc1.rar` instead of `my_doc.raraa`, `my_doc2.rar` instead of `my_doc.rarab` and so on but it didn’t work! Then how other people would be able to join those using software like WinRaR or UnRarX? Aren’t the generated files .rar files? However, I know I can join those on my Mac by using `cat` like this:

```
cat my_doc.rar* > my_doc.rar
```

But how would I be able to share the big file with people who don’t use a Mac?

Comment: `7-zip` seems to handle split `.rar` files in Windows without recombining.

Comment: what if the person does't have 7-zip? I want to send separate files as .rar @AFH

Comment: If the file is purely a binary split, then in Windows the standard command-line `copy` command will reassemble it, as in `copy /b file1+file2+file3+file4 file1234`; in Unix `cat` will achieve the same, as in `cat file1 file2 file3 file4 >file1234`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this from https://superuser.com/a/273380/54036

For splitting files to exact sizes, you could always use the command line tool Linux / Unix tool: split. The windows version is here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Using the tool you can split files to any size you would like, and you would use "cat" to recombine them.

For example:

```
split -b=10090000 bigfile.iso bigfile_part.
```

To split your files to exactly 10090000 bytes. Your output would look something like this:

```
bigfile_part.aa
bigfile_part.ab, etc.
```

To recombine just do:

```
cat bigfile_part* > bigfile.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've split a 8 GB my_doc.rar file into 4 separate files using the
>   following command from my Mac OS X 10.9 terminal
>   `split -b 2000m my_doc.rar my_doc.rar`

Ok, that cut one rar archive up into four parts.

> After splitting the file I've generated: my_doc.raraa, my_doc.rarab,
>   my_doc.rarac, and my_doc.rarad.

Yes, this is the default behavious. The first chunk gets `aa` appended to the name, the second ab, third ac etc. etc.

> Can I make the 4 files .rar just by removing the extensions?

No.  Compare it to a book. If you cut a book into four parts then you have four **parts**.  To make it a regular book it needs to have a cover with a title, an index etc etc.

For rar this is similar. It needs the previous parts to work.

> how other people would be able to join those using software like WinRaR
>   or UnRarX? Aren’t the generated files .rar files? However, I know I can
>   join those on my Mac by using cat like this:
>
> cat my_doc.rar* > my_doc.rar

In precisely the same way. You cut in in four. And later you appended ('glued') those fouyr back to one piece. In your case you used `cat` to do that, but there are many ways to do it. One of them which works on windows is copy. (`copy /b file1 + file2+ file3 + file4 bigfile`)

> But how would I be able to share the big file with people who don’t use
>   a Mac?

Let them use their own tools. Or use a different way to share smaller files. a chunked up rar file is a kludge. It would be much better to ask rar to produce a few smaller output files.