# How to run windows command shell "copy" from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to concatenate a bunch of 1GB files using PowerShell.  Normally I would do this in windows cmd.exe with, `copy /b file.txt.0+file.txt.1 file.txt`. However, the workstation I'm on has cmd.exe disabled.  **How can I run this same command in PowerShell?** When I run it exactly the same, I get the following error,

```
Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'file.txt'.
At line:1 char:1
+ copy /c file.txt.0+file.txt.1 file.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I've also tried this, but it seems to just overrite the output with whatever the last input file is,

```
copy -Path [file.txt.0, file.txt.1] -Destination file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy` in PowerShell is aliased to `Copy-Item` which is not the same as the Dos command `copy`. The follow command works great for large files and is very fast. In my case my powershell instance used about 42MB of memory when concatenating 8x1GB files.  CPU usage was also very low with my disk as the bottleneck.

`cmd /c copy /b file.txt.0+file.txt.1 file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I found an excellent answer using the PowerShell commands of
`Get-Content` and `Set-Content` instead of using CMD,
in the post
[How do I concatenate two text files in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749929/how-do-i-concatenate-two-text-files-in-powershell)

Here is the answer quoted entirely :

> Simply use the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Content) cmdlets:
>
> ```
> Get-Content inputFile1.txt, inputFile2.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
> ```
>
> You can concatenate more than two files with this style, too.
>
> If the source files are named similarly, you can use wildcards:
>
> ```
> Get-Content inputFile*.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
> ```
>
> **Note 1:** PowerShell 5 and older versions allowed this to be done more concisely using the aliases `cat` and `sc` for `Get-Content` and
> `Set-Content` respectively. However, these aliases are problematic
> because `cat` is a system command in *nix systems, and `sc` is a
> system command in Windows systems - therefore using them is not
> recommended, and in fact `sc` is no longer even defined as of
> PowerShell Core (v7). The PowerShell team [recommends against using
> aliases in general](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5862#issuecomment-357079132).
>
> **Note 2**: Be careful with wildcards - if you try to output to `inputFiles.txt` (or similar that matches the pattern), PowerShell
> will get into an infinite loop! (I just tested this.)
>
> **Note 3**: Outputting to a file with `>` does not preserve character encoding! This is why using `Set-Content` is recommended.

---

If `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` are too slow with large files,
streams are a good alternative.

Here is an (untested) script based on
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47352340/165358) :

```sh
$rootPath = "C:\temp"
$outputPath = "C:\test\somewherenotintemp.csv"
$streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter]$outputPath
Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Filter "*.csv" -File  | ForEach-Object{
    $file = $_.BaseName
    [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($_.FullName) | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $streamWriter.WriteLine(('{0},"{1}"' -f $_,$file))
        }
}
$streamWriter.Close(); $streamWriter.Dispose()
```

You will find more details in the linked answer.

Comment: Get-Content won't work for me.  concatenating even just 2 of the 1GB files uses more than 16GB of memory and is VERY slow compared to `copy`.

Comment: I added a more complex method, although I didn't test the code. Some knowledge of PowerShell will be required.

Comment: `Get-Content inputFile*.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt` - dangerous - might output the files in the wrong order